# WPF: Is there a way how to avoid TextBox text clipping when using Oblique FontStyle?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox

I am having a bit of a trouble when using **TextBox** in combination with an **oblique** text.

I took a look at a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51743565/wpf-cutting-the-part-of-the-last-letter-in-textblock-when-fontstyle-is-oblique) where the control used is actually a *TextBlock* and increasing the `Height` (as suggested) neither solves the problem for TextBox nor fits the needs of my scenario as I need the `Height` to be set implicitly based on the `Height` of the text inside the TextBox.

Apart from that, I was not able to find any other related questions.

**I have the following XAML code:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <TextBox
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        FontStyle="Normal"
        FontSize="50"
        Text="Another text">
    </TextBox>
</Window>
```

Everything looks fine until I change the `FontStyle` to `Oblique` (click on the links below to see the pictures):

[`FontStyle="Normal"`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klS8B.png)

[`FontStyle="Oblique"`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9AUv.png)

I found out the problem is probably caused by **TextBoxView** inside the TextBox which has its `Width` computed in a rather strange way. It seems that a portion of letter reaches outside of its "selection bounds" (when you take a look at the *selected text* and the *Snoop WPF element highlight* I am sure you will know what I mean).

[Selected text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZrDC.png)

[Snoop WPF element highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Da0z.png)

As it turns out, adjusting the TextBoxView `Width` in Snoop WPF resolves the problem. However, I am not able to achieve the same in XAML.

I could probably work this around by creating a custom template for TextBox, but it certainly seems like an overkill and an awful amount of work for something I would expect to be working properly in the first place.

**Did I miss something or is it really so difficult to get it working the right way?**

*PS: I really need the text to be selectable so using a TextBlock instead of TextBox is out of the question.*

Comment: Have you tried Padding="0,0,10,0"?

Comment: Yes, I have. The problem is, that the `Padding` will make the whole TextBox wider, but the red-bordered area (from this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Da0z.png)) will remain the same.
As a result, there will be an extra white area in the TextBox next to the text (or, if you will, the TextBoxView) but the text will be still clipped.

Comment: Have you tried setting a max-width?

Comment: Not before you mentioned it but then I gave it a try, although I was not sure how is that supposed to help since I actually want it to be _wider_ (so a `MinWidth` would make much more sense in this case). Setting `MaxWidth` indeed did not solve the problem. `MinWidth` helps, if set to the right value, but so can `Width` itself. The question is what is the right value. I need it to be set according to the space taken up by the text which, obviously, differs throughout the usages of TextBox.